# Open windows batch with prompt text but no invokation

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt

How can one open a batch window with some predefined text after the prompt and **not** invoking the command?

Say I want to invoke `notepad.exe` with a filename `t.txt`.

I would create a cmd file with this line:

```
start notepad "t.txt"
```

But I want the file to be opened specified by the user.

So the cmd file should just open a cmd window and "type" `start notepad` without actually executing this.

Comment: Do you just want to `echo` the command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using a Vbscript:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "cmd", 9 'opens cmd.exe
WScript.Sleep 500 'gives cmd a time to load
WshShell.SendKeys "start notepad"
```

If you want this within your cmd file, try this:

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /*
start cmd.exe
cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0"
exit/b
*/
var obj = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
obj.SendKeys("start notepad");
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 0):

Normally you'd have to launch a command prompt window: `start cmd` rather than starting notepad directly. But neither `start` nor `cmd` offer the function you desire. Would adding a simple `echo` to your batch file with instructions and a `pause` prior to actually issuing the command work?

```
Echo When the other operation completes return to this window
Pause
start notepad "t.txt"
```

This will provide the echo, then wait for the user to press any key before actually attempting to launch notepad with that filename.